# Do spring component classes have any scope, like spring beans?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, components

Spring beans have scopes like 'singleton', 'prototype', etc. Do spring components also have such scopes or something else which defines their life cycle?

Comment: What do you mean with spring components.

Comment: Java classes which we annotate with 'component' to make them available for scan by spring container

Comment: Those aren't Spring components those are regular Spring Beans as well.

Comment: So how do we define scopes for them? Additionally, what are spring components then?

Comment: With `@Scope` or the specialized annotations like `@RequestScope`, `@JobScope` etc. Spring components are, for me, the moving parts of Spring itself. Everything you configure yourself in xml, javaconfig or through component-scanning are Spring Beans.

Comment: But we configure @component ourselves too, and that makes them spring component, the difference being that we cannot tell spring how to create an instance or in what conditions

Comment: Yes you can and they are still beans managed by spring by my definition. From the view of the `ApplicationContext` there is no different in a bean defined through `@Component` an `@Bean` method or defined in XML. They are all the same and treated as beans.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can set scope with `@Scope("prototype")` annotation.